# Magento doesn't load template file

Tags: php, xml, magento

Whenever I navigate to the shopping cart when there's a product in it, it shows the header, footer and sidebars but not the cart content itself. I've checked with template hints and `frontend/base/default/template/page/html/notices.phtml` 
`frontend/base/default/template/catalog/msrp/popup.phtml`
 are the last two files that are loaded.

**Checkout.xml**

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
    <label>Shopping Cart</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>
    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
                <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.cart.form.before" as="form_before" translate="label">
                <label>Shopping Cart Form Before</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" translate="label">
                <label>Payment Methods After Checkout Button</label>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/multishipping_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" template="checkout/multishipping/link.phtml"/>
            </block>

            <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
            <block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
            <block type="checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>

            <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/cart/totals.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" translate="label">
        <label>Additional Product Info</label>
    </block>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

There are products in the cart

Comment: all showing fine in your checkout.xml file. may be from anywhere else your content overwriting. have you checked with Magento log file ??

Comment: @Chirag Nandaniya the system.log shows errors from a cache en attributes plugin and the exception.log shows an error from `invalid block type:Mage_Page_Block_Html_Spotlight` but I couldnt trace the last one back

Comment: have you checked the cart.phtml file exists? app/design/frontend/base/default/checkout/cart.phtml

Comment: @PixieMedia it exists in the base template as well as in the used template

Comment: And your question is? Also take a look in the merged layout XML (it's part of the request, you can read it out with a debugger or obtain if from cache) if the changes you want to apply are actually in there and at the right place. Please add the relevant parts from the merged layout XML to your question as well.